# Linux python shell can't get full program output

Tags: python, subprocess, popen

The task is to write a script that will automatically flash Intel network cards via nvmupdate64e.
I tried to write a script, but it hangs on processing nvmupdate64e output.

My script:

```
    nic_type = find_nic() # return nic [e810-True, v710-True] or False
    nic_e810 = 'cd /root/nic/nic/e810/E810/Linux_x64; ./nvmupdate64e -f'
    nic_v710 = 'cd /root/nic/nic/xvv710/Linux_x64; ./nvmupdate64e -f'
    if nic_type[0] == True:
        result = Popen(nic_e810, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
        while True:
            line = result.stdout.readline()
            if not line:
                break
            print("line from file2:", line)
```

Output:

```
line from file2: b'\n'
line from file2: b'Intel(R) Ethernet NVM Update Tool\n'
line from file2: b'NVMUpdate version 1.39.20.2\n'
line from file2: b'Copyright(C) 2013 - 2022 Intel Corporation.\n'
line from file2: b'\n'
line from file2: b'\n'
line from file2: b'WARNING: To avoid damage to your device, do not stop the update or reboot or power off the system during this update.\n'
```

Original output from Linux

```
Intel(R) Ethernet NVM Update Tool
NVMUpdate version 1.39.20.2
Copyright(C) 2013 - 2022 Intel Corporation.


WARNING: To avoid damage to your device, do not stop the update or reboot or power off the system during this update.
Inventory in progress. Please wait [***.......]


Num Description                          Ver.(hex)  DevId S:B    Status
=== ================================== ============ ===== ====== ==============
01) Intel(R) Ethernet Network Adapter   2.48(2.30)   159B 00:024 Update
    E810-XXV-2                                                   available

Options: Adapter Index List (comma-separated), [A]ll, e[X]it
Enter selection:
```

I think that python cannot intercept the console output completely. nvmupdate64 stops several times during operation to process data. I don't know how to intercept this output for processing and then continue execution.

I tried add poll()

```
while p.poll() is None:
    print (p.stdout.readline(1))
```

in while and received this output

```
b' '
b'['
b'.'
b'.'
b'.'
b'.'
b'.'
b'.'
b'.'
b'.'
b'.'
b'.'
b']'
b'\x08'
b'\x08'
b'\x08'
b'\x08'
b'\x08'
b'\x08'
b'\x08'
b'\x08'
b'\x08'
b'\x08'
b'\x08'
b'|'
b'\x08'
```

In original output that is [***.......]

Comment: The program seems to be waiting for input, AFAICT. So, either you give it input or you tell it (e.g. via a commandline flag) to operate non-interactively. BTW: Why `shell=True`? You could just as well start the executable directly and with the according working directory, but without a shell in between.

Comment: nic_e810 = '/root/nic/nic/e810/E810/Linux_x64/nvmupdate64e' I changed the code and removed Shell=True. But I am getting the same output as in the main post.